# Pattern Compiler for span html tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Hi I am working on a project in Cloud computing an amazon. Part of code where am stuck at is getting user wish list from amazon. 
Since there are permissions restrictions what I did was extracted the entire page source given the wish list url. To extract the itemID I used pattern compile like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/dp/(\\w+)/");
                    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(content);
```

This was easy and it now correctly lists all the products with their itemId in that wish list.
I also need the price for each. According to page source the price is

```
<span class="a-size-base a-color-price a-text-bold">
                      $7.19
                    </span>
```

I need to write a pattern for this one and am all confused and stuck.I suck at Regex expressions. Could anyone help please. I saw online references for href, but I don't think that will work for me.

Thanks to dkatzel I found this tool Jsoup. I tried the online conversion at [Online Jsoup Try](http://try.jsoup.org) so when I do CSS Query div I get the required output. But how do I hard code it in my java program. I have the jsoup jar.

Comment: I recommend you use a HTML parsing library like http://jsoup.org/ to do all this for you. (unless you need to parse it yourself for school work)

Comment: I don't need to parse it myself. My main project is completely different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: So what is the context that these prices appear in? Are they always in that kind of span tag with those class names?

Comment: Yes. These are the only tags which contain the price. I could attach the page source but it will be very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple expression work?

```
\\$\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)
```

`\\$` matches a literal `$`.

`\\d+` matches digits.

`(?:\\.\\d+)` matches potential decimals.

The whole match is what you're looking for I guess, unless you don't need the dollar symbol, then you can use either a capture group and take the first group (i.e. `\\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))`) or a lookbehind (i.e. `(?<=\\$)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)`)

Comment: I did    `List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
     Pattern pr=Pattern.compile("\\$\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)");
     Matcher priceMatcher= pr.matcher(content);

     while(priceMatcher.find()) {
      if(!price.contains(priceMatcher.group(1)))
       price.add(priceMatcher.group(1));
     }
     
     System.out.println("Prices fetched in iteration "+count);
     for(String s : price) {
      System.out.println(s);
     }`  **gives IndexOutOfBoundsException("No group " + group);**

Comment: @sa_nyc Use `.group(0)` since it's the whole match.

Comment: If you want to match the whole tag, you would use this however: `<span class="a-size-base a-color-price a-text-bold">\\s*(\\$\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))\\s*</span>` and then use `.group(1)` because there's a capture group.

Comment: Well worked with a small modification i.e. an escape character for double quotes within the tag. Thank you for saving the day

Comment: what do I do if I don't wanna match the $ symbol

Comment: @sa_nyc Then you can use something like that: `<span class=\"a-size-base a-color-price a-text-bold\">\\s*\\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))\\s*</span> and then use .group(1)`. And sorry about the quotes, I'm not quite used to Java's regex.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43447/discussion-between-sa-nyc-and-jerry)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative answer where Jsoup is used.

```
Element e = doc.select("span.a-size-base").first();
```

Include `jsoup-1.x.x.jar` in your project or when you compile, and add the following imports.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
```